# How to extract a particular number from a string of one column and store it in another column of data frame using R?

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame which look like:[Check The Data frame Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJpBF.jpg)

I am facing an issue while extracting the value of ID from cs.uri.query column and storing that particular value in another column in same data frame.
I tried a lot of methods like regex grep but still not able to solve.
Basically what result i want to get would something be like:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOa5O.jpg)

Need help solve this issue.Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you actually post a sample of your data and not just pictures of it. In your case, you may also be able to find the answer has already been given to a similar question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `str_match` function of the `stringr` library:

`library(stringr)
df$UserId <- str_match(df$cs.uri.query, "ID=([0-9]+)")[,2]`

This will search for any matches to `ID=<some number>` and return the first bracketed match, i.e. the number.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gsub` in base R...

```
df$UserID <- gsub(".*ID=([0-9]+).*","\\1",df$cs.uri.query)
```

This captures (in `()`) the string of digits after `ID=`, and replaces the whole string (hence the `.*` at either side, which means any characters) with the first (and only) captured group `\\1`.

I've not been able to test it on your data, but it should work.